# R select 80% from each user for training

Tags: r

The dataset represents user's preference on a bunch of movies. The goal is to obtain  `80%` of each user's rating to be in training.

If is setup the index of the entire data frame and split it by 80% there is no guarantee that It will give 80% from each user.

```
smple_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(df))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = smple_size)

train.shared <- df[train_ind, ]
test.shared <- df[-train_ind, ]
```

This will give 80% of the entire data frame. But each user may have rated a different number of movies.

```
movie_id, user_id, rated_value, feature_1, feature_2, genre, user_gender, user_ethnicity
101, 345, 3.5, 1, 1, comedy, male, white
101, 345, 3.5, 1, 2, comedy, male, white
101, 345, 3.5, 2, 1, comedy, male, white
125, 345, 4.5, 1, 4, drama, male, white
101, 233, 4.0, 1, 3, comedy, female, black
101, 233, 4.0, 2, 2, comedy, female, black
125, 233, 3.0, 1, 1, drama, female, black
125, 233, 3.0, 2, 2, drama, female, black
125, 333, 3.0, 1, 1, comedy, male, asian
125, 333, 3.0, 2, 2, comedy, male, asian
```

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly easy to accomplish using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  sample_frac(0.8)
```

to check:

```
set.seed(1)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  sample_frac(0.8) %>%
  pull(Species) %>%
  table

#output
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        40         40         40
```

while original data:

```
iris %>%
  pull(Species) %>%
  table
#output
setosa versicolor  virginica 
    50         50         50
```

A nice thing is that one can `group_by` multiple factors.

A base R approach using `by`:

```
set.seed(1)
index <- as.numeric(unlist(by(seq_along(iris[,"Species"]),
                              iris[,"Species"],
                              function(x) sample(x,
                                                 size = length(x)*0.8))))
```

does it work?

```
table(iris[index,5])
#output
setosa versicolor  virginica 
    40         40         40
```

Answer (score 1):

`createDataPartition()` in the `caret` package can be used to conduct stratified sampling. What's nice about this approach is it allows you to easily obtain both your training and test set for model building and validation:

```
library(caret)

sample <- caret::createDataPartition(y = df$user_id, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
```

If `list = FALSE`, it returns the indices of the observations in the sample:

```
in_df  <- df[sample, ]
out_df <- df[-sample, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no reason to not just use `dplyr`, `caret`, etc. in the majority of cases, but here's a Base R approach

```
# Create example dataset
set.seed(0)
user_id <- rep(1:10, sample(1:10, 10))
df <- data.frame(user_id = user_id, vals = runif(length(user_id)))


# Sort by user id
df <- df[order(df$user_id),]
# For each user ID, Create logical index which is T for ~80% of rows
split.lgl <- lapply(unique(df$user_id), function(x){
                n.rows <- sum(df$user_id == x)
                sample(n.rows) <= 0.8*n.rows})
# subset
train <- df[do.call(c, split.lgl),]
```